# Cesium library: error with constructor OLCesium

Tags: openlayers, html, cesium

I receive the error `olcs.OLCesium is not a constructor`

from line `var ol3d = new olcs.OLCesium({map: ol2d});` taken [here](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3-cesium/blob/master/examples/main.js)

my index.html looks like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/v3.16.0-dist/ol-debug.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/ol3-layerswitcher/src/ol3-layerswitcher.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/ol3-cesium-1.16/src/ol3cesium.js"></script>
```

and I have no problems using ol3 library (ol-debug.js). So I think my code works fine with lib paths.

UPDATE1:
from browser inspector I can see that the file ol3cesium.js is regularly downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

You need connect `libs/Cesium/Cesium.js`

`ol3cesium.js` replace `ol.js` and no need to use `ol.js`.